# Call update in Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I know there were similiar questions, but I see no solution in them. 
I want to create new object if it doesn't exists in database, and update if one exists. 
Here is my simple code :

```
  Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Tag", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Tag");
  query.equalTo("name", request.object.get("name"));
  query.first({
    success: function(result) {
        if (!result) {
            response.success();
        } else {
            result.increment("popularityCount");
            result.save();
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
       alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

As you see, I am calling it beforeSave. If query doesn't find anything, creates new entry. If query finds something, it should take this result, and `popularityCount`. But it doesn't. It works only if I call `response.success()` after that, but calling this function causes also in creating new entry.

Comment: typeof result === "undefined"   instead of !result ..... try that

Comment: thanks, but this part works fine, the problem is that results.save(); doesnt work if I won't call response.success() and if I call it, the new object is being created also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems wrong to increment a counter on an object on every save.  What if the object is modified for some other reason?  If you really do want to increment a field on every save, there's no need for a query -- the object being saved is passed to the function.  Moreover, a query *will not work* in the case where a new object is being saved.

How about instead, find or create the object as one operation, increment the counter when app logic calls for it

```
 function findOrCreateTagNamed(name) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Tag);
    query.equalTo("name", name);
    return query.first().then(function(tag) {
        // if not found, create one...
        if (!tag) {
            tag = new Tag();
            tag.set("popularityCount", 0);
            tag.set("name", name);
        }
        return (tag.isNew())? tag.save() : Parse.Promise.as(tag);
    });
}

function incrementPopularityOfTagNamed(name) {
    return findOrCreateTagNamed(name).then(function(tag) {
        tag.increment("popularityCount");
        return tag.save();
    });
}
```

Now there's no need for beforeSave logic (which seems like the right thing to do, not a workaround).

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Tag", function(request, response) {
    var tag = request.object;
    tag.increment("popularityCount");
    response.success();
});
```

Comment: `response.success()` automatically creates new record. I am trying your code now.

Comment: I got an `Result: {"code":124,"message":"Too many recursive calls into Cloud Code"}` in my logs from Parse.

Comment: oh, my bad.  its on before save, so we only want to save on  the new case.   you're right about response success.  please see edit.

Comment: Still to many recursive calls, I am thinking if it would be better if I just delete it on afterSave, because it seems that it's Parse.com issue

Comment: geez - see one more edit.  i was thinking i could do this without much review of your app logic, but we must set the created object's name so it **will be found** on the recursive save.  set it's popularityCount to zero so it will get incremented to 1 on the (single, hopefully) recursive call.

Comment: Thanks man, but Parse still puts "too many recursive calls" error. After almost 4 hours I will just do workaround for this, because it's seems as a Parse issue

Comment: @kodw - i realize i'm being stubborn here, but lets solve this correctly.  the whole original idea is a little strange (to increment on save only seems to make sense if you're counting saves of the object).  If the idea is to createOrFind, see edit for logic there.  if the idea is to increment on the new or found object, see edit for that.  if you really do want to increment on save, there's no reason to query, you have the object in hand.

Comment: Thats fine. The whole idea is that I have "Tags" which at first are new (popularity set to 0), but when some users use these Tags, I should increment popularityCount. So yes I am counting saves of the object. I am checking your code now